# Firefly in EEVEE in Volume

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I have firefly in EEVEE. Denoise is not helping in compositor neither.  Bloom is off.

Blender 3.0 beta. and 2.93 have it too.
How can I fix it without using Photoshop, since it is an animation sequence?

[image: EEVEE 128, volume 256, shadow 128.]

Comment: Beta versions of Blender aren’t really supported that well on Stack Exchange. This is probably a bug.

Comment: 2.93 have it too

Comment: OK, well do post that.